# I wouldn't mind if she goes/went rampage?

Tags: past-tense

Which one is correct?

> I wouldn't mind if she **goes** rampage on him.
>
> I wouldn't mind if she **went** rampage on him.

Comment: Can you describe what are you trying to say? Your usage of *rampage* is incorrect.

Comment: The second sentence has the structure of a conditional of the second type.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic expression is to **go *on a* rampage**.

It does not normally take an adjunct prepositional phrase like **on him** but I suppose it could, since speakers twist language into new shapes all the time.

There's a rather crude colloquialism in American English which comes to mind:

> I wouldn't mind if she went all ape-shit on his sorry ass.

Some speakers (myself included) would backshift to **went** there, because they are not expressing a fact about her but a possibility which they are contemplating. Her going all ape-shit on him is not a reality, merely a thought or notion. Other speakers would use the present **goes**.

Comment: can you also address the question of tense in the "if" phrase.